# Is there a way to see what kernel task is doing?

Tags: macos, kernel

I found a question (and answers) about [What exactly does kernel_task do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37366/what-exactly-does-kernel-task-do). What I want to know is how I can inspect what kernel_task is doing at any given moment in time?

Does it get logged so that I can inspect what is been doing for a while or can I even observe it at realtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does kernel\_task do?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37366/what-exactly-does-kernel-task-do)

Comment: That question asks something different than this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few places that information is available, but since kernel is a multitasking beast one has to look in multiple places:

1. The simple one is the Console log "type kernel in the filter box", but not all activity is reported there since Kernel issues millions of instructions in a Milli-second.
2. Also the Activity Monitor is a good source of information.
3. You could use the `ps -A > process.txt` to see all running processes.
4. You could use the `sudo iosnoop` to see all disk activity.
5. You could use `kextstat > ~/Desktop/kexts.txt` to see all loaded drivers.

In other words, it is too busy for you to follow and a continuous output file would not make senses.