# What's a normal value for kernel_task RAM usage?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, memory, kernel

Just bought a new MacBook Pro 12.1, early 2015 (Yosemite 10.10.4). I'm observing memory usage from `kernel_task` varying between 0.8-2.0 GB. Is it normal? Couldn't find a question referring to normal values.

Thanks

Comment: Check out what is that `kernel_task` do to get an idea of how much RAM it may need: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37366/what-exactly-does-kernel-task-do

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz, nice link, thank you. Still wondering what people with similar systems are experiencing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that amount is normal.

As kernel_task performs a lot of tasks on behalf of user-space processes (i.e. the ordinary programs you're running on your computer), the actual memory usage of kernel_task will vary a lot according to which programs you're currently running, and what you're doing with them.