# Kernel Task is taking up 1.12 GB in activity monitor

Tags: mac, memory, kernel-panic, activity-monitor, kernel

I have an issue where my kernel task is taking over a GB of memory on my activity monitor. My fan seems to be going pretty crazy and is loud. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37366/what-exactly-does-kernel-task-do for a good overview of what kernel_task is & does.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this ? Even I've similar issue with Mac Pro mid 2015 with 10.13.6 OS